# defining indexes and if statements

Tags: php, mysql, json, amazon-web-services

I am trying to map a collection of JSON files to a mysql database here is a sample of the json :

```
{

    "fileVersion": "1.0",
    "configurationItems": 

[

{

    "configurationItemVersion": "1.0",
    "configurationItemCaptureTime": "2014-12-12T17:14:09.005Z",
    "configurationStateId": 32,
    "relatedEvents": 

[

    "42d9f9c9-121c-4053-9ea8-451e98eeaf83"

],
"awsAccountId": "",
"configurationItemStatus": "OK",
"resourceId": "",
"ARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:037734006438:vpc/vpc-ab8390c9",
"awsRegion": "us-east-1",
"availabilityZone": "Multiple Availability Zones",
"configurationStateMd5Hash": "",
"resourceType": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
"tags": { },
"relationships":
[

{
```

using the following php I get an undefined index AWS::EC2::VPC error :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array();
$result='' ;
foreach(glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\views\*.json') as $filename)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($filename);

    if($json!=null)
    { 
        $decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
        //$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
        //$ss=$decode["array"]; 
        //echo $decoded['number']; 

        if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
        { 
            foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
            {
                //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

                $cfi=$configurationItems;


                if($cfi=(["resourceType"]["AWS::EC2::VPC"]))
                {
                        $configurationItemVersion=$cfi["configurationItemVersion"]; 
                          echo "<br />","configuration_Item_Version:",$configurationItemVersion,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationItemCaptureTime=$cfi["configurationItemCaptureTime"]; 
                          echo "configurationItemCaptureTime:",$configurationItemCaptureTime,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationStateId=$cfi["configurationStateId"]; 
                          echo "configurationStateId:",$configurationStateId,"<br />"; 
                        $awsAccountId=$cfi["awsAccountId"]; 
                          echo "awsAccountId:",$awsAccountId,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationItemStatus=$cfi["configurationItemStatus"]; 
                          echo "configurationItemStatus:",$configurationItemStatus,"<br />"; 
                        $resourceId=$cfi["resourceId"]; 
                          echo "resourceId:",$resourceId,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationStateMd5Hash=$cfi["configurationStateMd5Hash"]; 
                          echo "configurationStateMd5Hash:",$configurationStateMd5Hash,"<br />"; 
                        $resourceType=$cfi["resourceType"]; 
                          echo "resourceType:",$resourceType,"<br />";   
                        $ARN= isset($cfi["ARN"]) ? $cfi["ARN"] : ''; 
                          echo "ARN:",$ARN,"<br />";
                        $awsRegion= isset($cfi["awsRegion"]) ? $cfi["awsRegion"] : ''; 
                          echo "awsRegion:",$awsRegion,"<br />";  
                        $availabilityZone= isset($cfi["availabilityZone"]) ? $cfi["availabilityZone"] : ''; 
                          echo "availabilityZone:",$availabilityZone,"<br />";
                        $resourceCreationTime= isset($cfi["resourceCreationTime"]) ? $cfi["resourceCreationTime"] : ''; 
                          echo "resourceCreationTime:",$resourceCreationTime,"<br />";










                       $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     cfi_vpc(configuration_item_version,configuration_item_capture_time,configuration_state_id, aws_account_id, configuration_item_status, resource_id, arn, aws_region, availability_zone,configuration_state_md5_hash, resource_type, resource_creation_time)

                       VALUES('$configurationItemVersion','$configurationItemCaptureTime','$configurationStateId','$awsAccountId','$configurationItemStatus','$resourceId','$ARN','$awsRegion','$availabilityZone','$configurationStateMd5Hash','$resourceType','$resourceCreationTime' )")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 





                    // check if row inserted or not 
                    if ($result)
                    { 
                        // successfully inserted into database 
                        $response["code"] = 1; 
                        $response["message"] = "successfully updated configuration items volume"; 

                        // echoing JSON response 
                        echo json_encode($response); 
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        echo mysql_error();
                        // failed to insert row 
                        $response["code"] = 2; 
                        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

                        // echoing JSON response 
                        echo json_encode($response); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

the way that I imagine this to work is that if the resource type is equal to vpc or another type such as instance or security group the appropriate data is put into the correct tables thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($cfi=(["resourceType"]["AWS::EC2::VPC"]))
```

???? makes no sense

```
// check whether a the literal `AWS::EC2::VPC` equals
// the value of the element resourceType in $cfi
if( "AWS::EC2::VPC"===$cfi["resourceType"] )
```